# Access form width changes with screen width

Tags: ms-access

I' developing an access database, and I've tested it with different Access versions and different computers and everything worked well. Until by chance I found out that I get a problem with small screens, even when the have exactly the same resolution than my other screens. (Full HD Laptop screen) It seems to me that Access 'zooms' in at my forms. The forms look rather clumsy, and I get loads of errors because of form with (maybe the twips changed?). Fields, who can normally show a number, now show #### because of bigger font.

Is there an easy way to get Access showing the forms at the same scale?

(Also I found out that the Ribbon-Text is much smaller than the form text on this screen. On a normal screen it's not like that)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138901

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, found out that this is caused by the windows 'feature' text zoom. Disabling it solves the problem.